# Prove or disprove this upper bound on chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a simple connected finite graph and let $v \ge  4$ be  the number of vertices, $E$ the number of edges, $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number , $\omega(G)$ the clique number and  $\Delta$ the maximum degree of G. Let $C(G)$ be a function of $G$ which is equal to $3$ when $G$ contains cycles of odd length. 
Let $ {(d_1,d_2,...)}$ be the degree sequence of G.

Let $i > 4$ be the smallest integer such that

$$ \left\lceil \frac{(0.5\sum\limits_{j=1}^i d_j)  -i}{i-3} \right\rceil < \frac{i}{2}$$

and

$$ 2\frac{(0.5\sum\limits_{j=1}^i d_j)  -i}{i-3}  < \Delta $$

Take $i = v$ if a minimum value does not exist.

Let

$ B = 4  $  if $$ 1.5\leq\frac{(0.5\sum\limits_{j=1}^i d_j)  -i}{i-3} < 2 $$

Otherwise

$$ B = \left\lfloor 2\frac{(0.5\sum\limits_{j=1}^i d_j)  -i}{i-3} \right\rfloor  $$

Then

$$\chi(G) \le \max\left\{C(G) \ , B,\  \omega(G)\right\}$$

Comment: Probably your summation index should be $j=1$, rather than $i=1$?

Comment: Could you provide the concept/motivation? (Is $\ 0.5\ $ simply $\ \frac 12\ $ and $\ 1.5=\frac 32)\ $?